# Вопрос про HTTP запрос

Tags: python, http

Пытаюсь спарсить один ресурс, пишу программу на Python. Появилась небольшая проблема. При парсинге ресурса методом POST я передаю всю форму в точности как мой браузер, но вместо статус-кода 200 вылазит 409 ошибка с сообщением `ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта`. Не понимаю к чему это. Что нужно поменять, чтобы всё заработало?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в заголовках, нужно передавать не только данные формы, а весь корректный запрос,включая заголовок user-agent и т.д. Наверняка проблема именно в этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, некоторые данные, которые не запрашивались в форме, запрашивались в заголовках (спасибо комментатору noname2019).